# fetching values from two tables based on each table having different conditions in django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-views

i have 2 models test1 and test2. 
i want to query status condition from test1 and progress condition in test2 .

**class test1:**

```
iID                     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
iEID                    = models.BigIntegerField(_("EID"),default=0)
istatus                 = models.BooleanField(_("Status"),default=0)
```

**class test2:**

```
iid                     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
iEID                    = models.BigIntegerField(_("EID"),default=0)
progress                = models.IntegerField(_("pgs"),blank=True,null=True)
```

i want query something like progess > 7 in test2 model and istatus = 1 in test1 model and **common field** for both tables is **iEID**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
test1_list = test1.objects.filter(istatus=1).values_list('id','iEID')

test2_queryset = test2.objects.filter(progress__gt=7, iEID__in=[y for x, y in test1_list] )

test1_queryset = test1.objects.filter( iEID__in=test2_queryset.values_list('iEID') , id__in = [x for x, y in test1_list])
```

Now `test1_queryset` and `test2_queryset` will be having the objects whose  `progess > 7` , `istatus = 1` and common `iEID`

Comment: can this be possible using one-to-one relation in django ??

Comment: In a `one-to-one` relationship, one record in a table is associated with one and only one record in another table.
for example the inbuilt django `auth_user` model which has `username, password, email` will be a one to one with another `userdetail` model which can have extra informations of that user like `medical details, identification marks`.

From what I understood by seeing your models the relation which you need is `Many-to-many`.
A `many-to-many` relationship occurs when multiple records in a table are associated with **multiple records** in another table.